# A themeless noncryptic

Tags: crosswords

[image]

### ACROSS

**1.** Go away
**4.** Planned major port on the Pacific coast
**6.** Overreactive
**9.** 1940s escape routes from Europe
**10.** NEXT, for example
**11.** Olympiad champion
**12.** Vow
**14.** A Scottish Monday
**16.** Pinnacle
**19.** Someone from Dallas, for example
**22.** Something worth reporting
**24.** Canton legislatures
**26.** Out of perfectly thin air
**29.** Matt Hawk
**30.** A psychological manipulation
**31.** King with donkey ears
**32.** An antelope
**33.** Fibers

### DOWN

**1.** 1950s sex symbol
**2.** 1940s-'50s British politico
**3.** Extensions from the body
**4.** Taking land elsewhere: Br.
**5.** Middle-aged or older
**6.** Modem instructions
**7.** Raffle
**8.** Despondent
**13.** Teddy bear, for example
**15.** Milled
**17.** Fools
**18.** A Swiss theologian
**20.** Someone at a conference, for example
**21.** A device for holding a flask
**23.** A fluke, for example
**25.** Japanese drinks
**27.** More recent
**28.** Teacakes

---

### Apology and clarification:

I realized only now (meaning at this writing, which is some time *after* posting the puzzle) that the answer to **1 down** is spelled wrong. You should probably ignore **1 down** when solving the puzzle (though you should be able to fill it in with its spelling mistake at some point in your solving). I apologize.

---

### Hints, added after the original puzzle posting:

As hints, I present easier (some of them much easier) versions of some of the clues above. Each is hidden separately so that your solving the puzzle need not be spoiled more than you wish it to be.

1 across

> Go away!

4 across

> Planned major port on the Pacific coast of Mexico

10 across

> NEXIS or NEXT, for example

12 across

> To vow

14 across

> A Scottish Monday in January

24 across

> Some cantons' legislatures

30 across

> An attempt to win people over by alarming them

1 down

> Actress, a 1950s sex symbol

4 down

> Taking and populating a distant land: British English

6 down

> Hayes modem instructions

7 down

> A raffle

15 down

> Milled an old-fashioned way

17 down

> Fools or dolts

18 down

> A 20th-century Swiss theologian

21 down

> A device for holding a flask or beaker

23 down

> A parasitic fluke, for example

25 down

> Some Japanese drinks

28 down

> Some teacakes

---

### More hints, added even later:

Here's the grid with twenty answer letters added here and there:

> [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**COMPLETED GRID!**

> [image: Complete]

Many thanks to jafe and Stiv for their contributions...a true team effort! The trick is:

> Some letters have been replaced by numeric/symbolic equivalents. So for example, "1" is used in place of "one", "|" in place of "bar", "@" in place of "at", "&" in place of "and", etc.

**ACROSS**

> 1A - BEAT IT
>  4A - COLONET
>  6A - ATOPIC (h/t Stiv)
>  9A - RATLINES (h/t jafe)
>  10A - ION ENGINE (thanks OP)
>  11A - MEDALIST
>  12A - SWEAR
>  14A - HANDSEL (h/t jafe)
>  16A - NE PLUS ULTRA
>  19A - LONE STAR STATER
>  22A - NEWS EVENT (h/t Stiv)
>  24A - LANDRATS
>  26A - EX NIHILO
>  29A - TWO-GUN KID
>  30A - SCARE TACTIC
>  31A - MIDAS
>  32A - ELAND
>  33A - STRANDS

**DOWN**

> 1D - BARDOT
>  2D - ATTLEE
>  3D - TENTACLES
>  4D - COLONISATION
>  5D - THIRTY PLUS
>  6D - AT COMMANDS (h/t jafe and tip from OP)
>  7D - PRIZE DRAW  (h/t Stiv)
>  8D - CHEERLESS
>  13D - PLUSHY
>  15D - STONEGROUND
>  17D - LUNKHEADS (h/t Stiv)
>  18D - BARTH
>  20D - ATTENDEE
>  21D - RING STAND
>  23D - FLATWORM
>  25D - SAKES (fixed per OP)
>  27D - LATER
>  28D - SCONES

Comment: Nice! rot13(9n: e@yvarf, 14n: u&fry, 6q: ngqgf)

Comment: Ah, no way! @msh210 I was genuinely working on creating a crossword with this exact mechanic for the novelty crosswords FTC but didn't get it finished to my satisfaction in time :) Can't believe I didn't spot this at play here...!

Comment: Nicely found, Jeremy Dover. Everything here is correct except 6 down, which needs generalization (you're looking at a too-specific type of instruction).

Comment: Thanks @msh210...I was not convinced by that either. Will keep working/compiling...shoot I see it...6d is bloody brilliant!

Comment: I think your 22A should be rot13(NEW7T) so that 17D can be something like rot13(YHAXURNQF) and 7D can end in rot13(QENJ)

Comment: In fact, rot13(6N pbhyq or NGBCVP fb gung 7Q pbhyq or CEVMRQENJ)

Comment: @Stiv I see what you're doing there. Think you're right, am updating.

Comment: Well done!! Everything is right except 10 across, which is rot13([VbarATVAR](http://enwp.org/ion_engine)). (Oh, and 25 down is usually spelled with an E, not an I.)

Comment: Oh (I just realized this isn't what you have), 27 down was meant to be rot13(YngGRE).